# Global objects constructors called after first use of object

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, global

As far as I know the constructors of global objects need to be called before anybody tries using those objects. However in my program this doesn't seem to be the case. Here is my simplified code (I compile it with gcc version 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct type_data
{
    int id;

    type_data()
        : id(-1) // set some invalid id
    {
        cout << "creating a new type data" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct type_data_for_type
{
    static type_data data;
};
template <typename T>
type_data type_data_for_type<T>::data;


struct type_registry
{
    static type_registry& instance()
    {
        static type_registry i;
        return i;
    }

    void register_type(type_data& t)
    {
        cout << "registering a type" << endl;
        t.id = last_id++;
    }

    int last_id;
};

template <typename T>
struct registrator
{
    registrator()
    {
        type_registry::instance().
            register_type(type_data_for_type<T>::data);
    }

    int unused;
    static registrator payload;
};
template <typename T>
registrator<T> registrator<T>::payload;

class foo {};

inline void register_foo()
{
    registrator<foo>::payload.unused = 1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << type_registry::instance().last_id << endl;
    cout << type_data_for_type<foo>::data.id << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically it registers the type foo globally via register_foo. I expect the output to be:

```
creating a new type data
registering a type
1
0
```

But instead it is:

```
registering a type
creating a new type data
1
-1
```

This means that i've set the id of a `type_data` object before its constructor was called.

So, is this a compiler bug? Am I missing something? Can I make this work?

Comment: i believe you cannot rely on the relative order of construction of global objects

Comment: Relevant: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html [10.14] What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you cannot rely on the order of initialization of static member variables of class templates in this case.

Relevant here is § 3.6.2/2 of the C++ Standard:

*"Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is either ordered or
unordered. Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have ordered initialization. **Other class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) **have unordered initialization***."

And of course also § 9.4.2/6, which refers the above rule:

*"Static data members are initialized and destroyed exactly like non-local variables (3.6.2, 3.6.3)."*

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `registrator<foo>::payload` is being initialized before `type_data_for_type<foo>::data`. The constructor of `registrator<foo>`, however, uses `type_data_for_type<foo>::data`.

You can't rely on static initializers being called in any particular order and, in your case, it's happening in exactly the wrong order compared to what you want.

What I think the underlying problem is, though, is that your solution is over-complicated. Do you really need to distinguish between `type_data_for_type` and `registrator`? Can't a type data object register itself?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is a simplified version of the code. In reality I need to be able to access the type data (which contains a lot more than an id) for a type in template functions.

Comment: The more idiomatic way to access type data in template functions is with traits.

Comment: but then I'd have to manually specialize my traits structures, while in this case the data is automatically filled.